# PayPal REST API shipping address Codeigniter

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

How to get shipping address with `TOKEN` using paypal REST api? I found [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/) useful but I cant see example of usage anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue a lot and finally found solution, so I want to share it if anyone else need it.

So question: **How to get order details with `TOKEN`?**

Add this function :

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
      $environment = 'sandbox'; // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

      // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
      $API_UserName = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxx');
      $API_Password = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxx');
      $API_Signature = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxx');
      $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
      if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
      }
      $version = urlencode('85.0');

      // Set the curl parameters.
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

      // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

      // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
      $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

      // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

      // Get response from the server.
      $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

      if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit('$methodName_ failed: '.curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
      }

      // Extract the response details.
      $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

      $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
      foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
          $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
      }

      if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
      }

      return $httpParsedResponseAr;
    }
```

and simply make a call to that function :

```
// Set request-specific fields.
$token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($data['TOKEN'])); //$data['TOKEN'] is token
// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);
print_r($httpParsedResponseAr); // will hold all details such as shipping address, country...
```

additionally you can add check if payment was successful:

```
if( "SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) ) { .. }
```

[reference](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/ES/es_ES/files/developer/nvp_ECGetExpressCheckout_php.txt)